# MySQL LIMIT X, Y slows down as I increase X

Tags: mysql, database, performance, pagination, mariadb

I have a db with around 600 000 listings, while browsing these on a page with pagination, I use this query to limit records:

```sql
SELECT file_id, file_category FROM files ORDER BY file_edit_date DESC LIMIT 290580, 30
```

On first pages `LIMIT 0, 30` it loads in few ms, same for `LIMIT 30,30`, `LIMIT 60,30`, `LIMIT 90,30`, etc. But as I move forward to the end of the pages, the query takes around 1 second to execute.

Indexes are probably not related, it also happens if I run this:

```
SELECT * FROM `files` LIMIT 400000,30
```

Not sure why.
Is there a way to improve this ?

Unless there is a better solution, would it be a bad practice to just load all records and loop over them in the PHP page to see if the record is inside the pagination range and print it ?

> Server is an i7 with 16GB ram; 
>   MySQL Community Server 5.7.28; 
>   files table is around 200 MB

here is the my.cnf if it matters

```
query_cache_type = 1

query_cache_size = 1G

sort_buffer_size = 1G

thread_cache_size = 256

table_open_cache = 2500

query_cache_limit = 256M

innodb_buffer_pool_size = 2G

innodb_log_buffer_size = 8M

tmp_table_size=2G

max_heap_table_size=2G
```

Comment: Are you after a [pagination alternative](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/pagination)?

Comment: It looks like I am. It needs to go trough all records in order to reach the given limit(s), I wasn't expecting this to be such a pain.

Comment: If your rows have a `id UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT, PRIMARY KEY(id)`. Then you can just use `WHERE id>? && id<?`.

Comment: I think that would not work when I need to select just files from a certain category, and if I understand correctly, this only works when there are no deleted items. 
I found an easier way, in urls instead of `?page=1`, `page=2` I will simply use `?date=TIMESTAMP` that will allow me to jump straight to the right `file_edit_date` limit.

Comment: I see what you're saying about `DELETE` issue matching where you would start. Why not, instead of a `PRIMARY KEY`, just store your count in a variable?

Comment: it would probably work to create a custom index that will contain no gaps, but that would need to be updated very often in order to work. I went with the `?file_edit_date=x` in pagination instead of `?page=x`, seems to be fast and reliable.

Answer (score 0):

You may find that adding the following index will help performance:

```
CREATE INDEX idx ON files (file_edit_date DESC, file_id, file_category);
```

If used, MySQL would only need a single index scan to retrieve the number of records at some offset.  Note that we include the columns in the select clause so that the index may cover the entire query.

Comment: I added some details. Are indexes still related if it also runs this query slow ? `SELECT * FROM files LIMIT 400000,30` ? And runs fast if it starts from lower number.

Comment: You need to run `EXPLAIN` to better understand what MySQL is actually doing, but my suggestion should perform well in most cases.

Comment: The `file_id` and `edit_date` are already in an index, I should have mentioned that, but I found more info, it looks like there is a known limitation, it needs to go trough all the rows in order to stop where I want it to, and that takes time. I will try to add like a gap-less column `file_pagination_index` so I can then tell it load from 60 to 90.

Comment: Caveat:  Before 8.0, `DESC` in an `INDEX` declaration is ignored.  In this particular case, this caveat does not matter since the other columns are there only to be "covering" and the Optimizer is willing to scan the table backward.

Comment: Wait a minute, I was not focused properly, I just noticed the `DESC` on the above index, so does this mean that this new index helps by processing the items backward ? Helping with the current sluggishness at the end pages ?

Comment: @adrianTNT Read the comment by Rick above.

Answer (score 0):

LIMIT was invented to reduce the size of the result set, it can be used by the optimizer if you order the result set using an index.

When using `LIMIT x,n` the server needs to process x+n rows to deliver a result. The higher the value for *x*, the more rows have to be processed.

Here is the explain output from a simple table, having an unique index on column *a*:

```
MariaDB [test]> explain select a,b from t1 order by a limit 0, 2;
+------+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+-------+
| id   | select_type | table | type  | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra |
+------+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+-------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | t1    | index | NULL          | PRIMARY | 4       | NULL | 2    |       |
+------+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [test]> explain select a,b from t1 order by a limit 400000, 2;
+------+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+--------+-------+
| id   | select_type | table | type  | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref  | rows   | Extra |
+------+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+--------+-------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | t1    | index | NULL          | PRIMARY | 4       | NULL | 400002 |       |
+------+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+--------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

When running the statements above (without EXPLAIN) the execution time for LIMIT 0 is 0.01 secs, for LIMIT 400000 0.6 secs.

Since MariaDB doesn't support LIMIT in a subquery, you could split your SQL statements in to two statements:

The first statement retrieves the id's (and needs to read the index file only), the second statement uses the id's retrieved from first statement:

```
MariaDB [test]> select a  from t1 order by a limit 400000, 2;
+--------+
| a      |
+--------+
| 595312 |
| 595313 |
+--------+
2 rows in set (0.08 sec)

MariaDB [test]> select a,b from t1 where a in (595312,595313);
+--------+------+
| a      | b    |
+--------+------+
| 595312 | foo  |
| 595313 | foo  |
+--------+------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Interesting -- I tried 4 variants of that `EXPLAIN`, only one showed 400002; the rest showed (about) the number of rows in the table.  Furthermore, the last version of MariaDB that showed a realistic limit was 10.0.

Answer (score 0):

Caution:  I am about to use some strong language.  Computers are big and fast, and they can handle bigger stuff than they could even a decade ago.  But, as you are finding out, there are limits.  I'm going to point out multiple limits that you have threatened; I will try to explain why the limits may be a problem.

**Settings**

```
query_cache_size = 1G
```

is terrible.  Whenever a table is written to, the QC scans the 1GB looking for any references to that table in order to purge entries in the QC.  Decrease that to 50M.  This, alone, will speed up the entire system.

```
sort_buffer_size = 1G
tmp_table_size=2G
max_heap_table_size=2G
```

are bad for a different reason.  If you have multiple connections performing complex queries, lots of RAM could be allocated for each, thereby chewing up RAM, leading to swapping, and possibly crashing.  Don't set them higher than about 1% of RAM.

In general, do not blindly change values in my.cnf.  The most important setting is `innodb_buffer_pool_size`, which should be bigger than your dataset, but no bigger than 70% of *available* RAM.

**load all records**

Ouch!  The cost of shoveling all that data from MySQL to PHP is non-trivial.  Once it gets to PHP, it will be stored in structures that are not designed for huge amounts of data -- 400030 (or 600000) rows might take 1GB inside PHP; this would probably blow out its "memory_limit", leading PHP crashing.  (OK, just dying with an error message.)  It is possible to raise that limit, but then PHP might push MySQL out of memory, leading to swapping, or maybe running out of swap space.  What a mess!

**OFFSET**

As for the large `OFFSET`, why?  Do you have a user paging through the data?  And he is almost to page 10,000?  Are there cobwebs covering him?

`OFFSET` must read and step over 290580 rows in your example.  That is costly.

For a way to paginate without that overhead, see http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/pagination .

If you have a program 'crawling' through all 600K rows, 30 at a time, then the tip about "remember where you left off" in that link will work very nicely for such use.  It does not "slow down".

If you are doing something different; what is it?

**Pagination and gaps**

Not a problem.  See also:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/deletebig#deleting_in_chunks which is more aimed at walking through an entire table.  It focuses on an efficient way to find the 30th row going forward.  (This is not necessarily any better than remembering the last `id`.)

That link is aimed at `DELETEing, but can easily be revised to`SELECT`.

Some math for scanning a 600K-row table 30 rows at a time:

My links:  600K rows are touched.  Or twice that, if you peek forward with  `LIMIT 30,1` as suggested in the second link.

`OFFSET ..., 30` must touch (600K/30)*600K/2 rows -- about 6 *billion* rows.

(Corollary:  changing 30 to 100 would speed up your query, though it would still be painfully slow.  It would not speed up my approach, but it is already quite fast.)